# Records between 2 dates Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am looking to filter out records between 2 dates. Here is a list of start and end dates. I need identify records that fall under the respective periods.
I am able to identify the records that fall in the first and last period i.e. first (9/07/2020 - 22/07/2020) and last (10/11/2020 - 23/12/2020) by using MIN and MAX. I am not able to find records that fall in between i.e. 2-11?

[image]

I have another table that shows a date when the records were updated. For instance,

[image]

I need to identify the records that falls under what periods. For instance,

[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a `between` expression would do it, e.g. `t2.change_date between t1.startdate and t1.enddate`. Something like that?

Comment: I have done something like that, but it is vert tedious as i have a lot of dates.

Comment: Please read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a join on your two tables. You don't give your table names, so this is a bit of guesswork, but try something like this:

```
select * 
  from period_table p
 inner join record_table r on r.changed_date between p.startdate and p.enddate
```

Comment: ohh shit. That worked. I did not realise I could so something like that.
Thank you!